# C# how to reveal picture after entering password

Tags: c#, passwords, visibility, picturebox

I made a form with a textbox for a user to enter a password and if the password is "hello", it'll reveal the pictureBox. I have the pictureBox visibility set to false. I have no clue how to do this, and have looked just about everywhere with no luck (yes, I'm a beginner).

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    string secretPassword = "hello";
    public event EventHandler VisibleChanged;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == secretPassword)
        {
            pictureBox1.VisibleChanged+= new EventHandler(this.PictureBox1_VisibleChanged) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just set the `Visible` property

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: you're subscribing to the event that fires after visibility changes, which is not helpful here. You just want to set `pictureBox1.Visiblity = true` (or `Visibility.Visible`, i forget which)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're setting up an event handler rather than modifying the property.

The `pictureBox1.VisibleChanged+= new EventHandler(this.PictureBox1_VisibleChanged) ;` line is only adding a new event handler (this doesn't help much).

It should read:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Calling the `Refresh()` method will force the picture box to update and show on the button click.

[This question goes into detail about threads and how they relate to UI component visibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084367/toggling-picture-box-visibility-c-sharp)